# Thread safe optimized list

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Last week I was challenged in a technical interview with a code challenge about threads and efficiency.
The challenged required to create a service to detect whether an ID had been already seen or not.
The requirements were simple:

- Return true or false if a given id was already seen or not
- Duplicates are not allowed, this is critical
- False positives can be tolerated at a maximum error rate of less than 1%
- Must be thread safe to call
- No 3rd party packages can be used
- create the implementation as efficiently as possible in both locking, memory usage, and cpu usage

I was provided with the following code:

```
public interface IDuplicateDetectionService
{
    bool Seen(int id);
}

public class Service : IDuplicateDetectionService
{
    public bool Seen(int id)
    {
        if (id < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id));
        }
    }
}
```

My solution was this:

```
public class Service : IDuplicateDetectionService
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> _itemsSeen = new HashSet<int>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public bool Seen(int id)
    {
        if (id < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id));
        }

        if (_itemsSeen.Contains(id))
        {
            return true;
        }

        lock(_lock)
        {
            return _itemsSeen.Add(id) == false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the test code this:

```
private void Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var maxDegreeOfParalellism = 1000;
    var idCount = 1000000;
    var successfulCalls = 0;
    var failedCalls = 0;
    var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, idCount);

    var servie = new Service();
    var testService = new Action<int>(id =>
    {
        var seen= service.Seen(id);
        if (seen == false)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref successfulCalls);
        }
        else
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref failedCalls);
        }
    });

    // Act
    Parallel.ForEach(
        ids,
        new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParalellism
        },
        currentId => testService(currentId));

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(idCount, successfulCalls);
    Assert.Equal(0, failedCalls);
}
```

The code worked and the test passed, however, I don't think I matched the expectations.
To begin with, I don't understand the requirement stating **error rate of less than 1%**, on the other hand, I don't know how to refactor that code so that it satisfies the conditions.

I didn't get possitive feedback, which is fine, but I didn't get what a possible solution would be, which I would have liked to get.
I would like to learn how that case could be solved following the given requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: Implementation looks fine for me. But the test doesn't cover the `true` scenario.

Comment: Yes, I don`t realize how to test the failure scenario, where I get that 1% of failures.
I don't also quite understand how to improve that in terms of efficiency.
Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: 1%? Implement it with `HashSet` and locks but make as less lock time as possible in terms of performance e.g. reader/writer lock. Then return `true` if writer lock was already taken regardless of `id` value. Here's possible false positive. Compare performance with the 1st implementation then.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting! Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try and will come back with the results

Comment: I added the refactored code. After carefully evaluating your advise, it made a lot of sense.

Comment: Not a thread-safe. `_itemsSeen.Contains(id)` can be called while `_itemsSeen.Add(id)` is working. Imagine 2 threads: (1) Checks `_isLocked` which is false; (2) set `isLocked` to true and execute `_itemsSeen.Add(id)`; (1) at the same time calls `_itemsSeen.Contains(id)`. Oops. :) Tip is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement), you need just to wisefully use `Monitor` class.

Comment: i know, It is an early check, however, Add would return false if the key was present.
So basically there is no sense in getting into the lock if the key was there, and since I am only adding, worst case is what you mentioned. Does it make sense?
Taking a look at you tip now

Comment: `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` are your friends here :) What is reader/writer lock: any Thread can read while writer lock is not taken, no Thread can write while reader lock is taken. How to write if reader lock always taken (hot activity)? Hold new readers to enter while all old readers finish their jobs and take the writer lock then. Another tip: You probably need more than two different (independent) locks to implement it. Now you have only one.

Comment: I see, I am trying to understand and digest your proposal. I know it is a pain, but would you mind writing some fachade code? I am strugling at it right now

Comment: Ok :) don't hurry up but read this carefully: [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=netframework-4.8). Then to understand it implement own with `Monitor` to meet the challenge requirements.

Comment: I don't understand, the test code seems wrong to me. You have 10,000 _unique_ ids so you're expecting 0 duplicates so `successfulCalls` should be close to 0. Your solution is also wrong. `TryAdd` returns true if the item was *added* so you should be returning `!itemsSeen.TryAdd(...`. Am I missing something?

Comment: That test is the basic one serving as an example. Regarding `TryAdd`, you are right, I just made a mistake when created the snippet. I'll edit the answer with the latest version of the code.